# Post array from HTML form, and use results to update multiple rows in a mysql table

Tags: php, mysql, html, arrays, forms

So I have this basic html form. My goal is to pass the values submitted to this form into a mysql table.

```
 <form action="?action=settings" method="post">
      <ul>
        <li>
           <label for="settingValue[1]">Setting 1:</label>
           <input type="text" name="settingValue[1]" id="setting1" required />
        </li>
        <li>
            <label for="settingValue[2]">Setting 2:</label><br>
            <input checked type="radio" name="settingValue[2]" value="1" />On<br>
            <input type="radio" name="settingValue[2]" value="0" />Off
         </li>
         <li>
             <input type="submit" name="saveChanges" value="Save Changes" />
         </li>
       </ul>
   </form>
```

My mysql table has only 3 columns (id, settingName, settingValue)
So I want to update multiple records in my table using this form (In this case rows 1 and 2) by storing the value into the "settingValue" column.

After some research I found that what seems to be the best way to do this would be by posting an array (Which is what I attempted to do above), then use a foreach loop to to run through the array and update the table.

I guess my main problem is figuring out how to use the array.  Because I need to UPDATE a record NOT create a new one. I also need to retain the ID so I can update the corresponding record.

After hours of googling my best guess was to do this:

```
if ( isset( $_POST['saveChanges'])) {
    foreach($_POST['settingValue'] as $key => $settingValue )  {
        $conn = new PDO( DB_DSN, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD );
        $conn->exec("UPDATE settings SET settingValue=$settingValue WHERE id=$key");
        $conn = null;
    }
```

But it is yielding no results.

Comment: Try to `echo` your SQL query and copy-paste it to mysql console. You'll see errors if any

Comment: + try to enclose value `SET` value in quotes (') or (")

`UPDATE settings SET settingValue='$settingValue' WHERE id='$key'`

Comment: also try `print_r($_POST['settingValue'])` or `print_r($_POST)` and inspect the array.

Comment: Tip: `label for=` must point to the `id` of an element, not the `name`.

Comment: Thanks WouterH for the tip never knew that! I always had the name and the id the same so I never knew the difference... :/ but now i do :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep `$settingValue` and `$key` in quotes:

```
$conn->exec("UPDATE settings SET settingValue='$settingValue' WHERE id='$key'");
```

Tip: Keep `$conn = new PDO( DB_DSN, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD );` outside the `foreach` loop. No need to repeat the connection on each loop

Comment: Perfect! I can't believe it was something so simple! Thanks asprin :)

Comment: Note that this is prone to sql injection. You might want to use bind parameters.

Comment: i had it bound in the original but took it out to post here. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Summing up all proposed solutions I would add.

Array `keys` as `recordID` is Ok to keep info about parameters for multiple records.

Looping is better to organize next way (to **reuse** existing connection, but not to *reopen* on each iteration):

```
$conn = new PDO( DB_DSN, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD ); // opened connection
if ( isset( $_POST['saveChanges'])) // if smth. POSTed
    foreach($_POST['settingValue'] as $key => $settingValue ) // LOOPing thorugh each item
        $conn->exec("UPDATE settings SET settingValue='".$settingValue."' WHERE id='".$key."'"); // executing query using the previously opened connection
```

And try to enclose value `SET` value in quotes (`'`) or (`"`) `UPDATE settings SET settingValue='$settingValue' WHERE id='$key'`.